# Can I access apache2 localhost sites in var/www from a mobile device?

Tags: apache, mobile

I'm able to load the Apache default page located at var/www/html on my mobile device by typing in my computers IP address (both are connected to the same wifi router). However, my local sites are all virtual hosts defined in var/www/ (i.e. the parent folder) - I've tried all the logical approaches I can think of, e.g. / or http://, etc

is there a way to access the virtual hosts via my mobile device?

Comment: Modify your documentRoot to point to var/www.  If Apache is configured to point to var/www/html, Apache will not allow you to move up 1 directory without modifying configuration, for security.

Comment: Thanks, that motivated me to take a look... actually apache2.conf sets /var/www as root, which is why i can place a website folder there and just type the folder name followed by / in my browser - i would need to modify the hosts file to define localhost as /var/www/ rather than /var/www/html/ - but on reflection I think I'd rather just move any folder I want to preview on mobile to the ./html folder - which how apache2 is intended to be used it seems.